# Physically based explanation for glowing geometric shapes found embedded in a city, visible only in IR

Tags: science-based, aliens, environment, electromagnetism

I'm looking for an explanation for the presence of large geometric luminescent formations that are found to be embedded in the infrastructure of a city.

They must be esentially undetectable to the average human but show up clearly on special cameras (mid/far infrared or Thz gap). These formations could effect humans or their environment but only in ways that are hard for an average person to notice, or easy to attribute to other causes.

The best explanation would be the most linked to our current understanding of physics, but need not be the most probable.

When imaged they might appear something like this:

[image: LED sculpture by Jun Ong]
Thanks a lot

Comment: Advertisements by and for our insect overlords (whom I, for one, welcome).

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  OK, I hate to say it, but this question is by definition [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#6437) because "coolest" is 100% subjective.  Our [help/on-topic] explains that questions must be specific and answerable, must include context, must include restrictions/requirements, and should include research.

Comment: However, off the record, I love the idea.  Regrettably, this site is much less about creative writing than you might think.  Our [help/on-topic] also states that "the goal of the site is to help you build your world, not to tell your story."

Comment: Liam, it's bad form to edit a question to that extent without the OP's permission - and you didn't solve the problem.  "Most plausible" is as vague and POB as "coolest."  Please only edit for grammatical clarity unless given permission.  Part of the goal is to help the OP learn how to ask questions.

Comment: I’ve edited your question to try and make it less opinion based. Please add in a criteria for a best answer, i’ve gave the best one i can based on what was already in the answer but i don’t know what you are looking for. Also, try and avoid terms that are very opinion based.

Comment: @JBH Unfortunately, i was in a review when i edited the question so did not get the opportunity to post a comment after i edited it (though, as you can see, i posted my comment at roughly the same time you posted your own). As i say, whilst both are subjective terms, there not much i can do about that without a crystal ball, only the OP knows what they are looking for.

Comment: I've retagged this but not sure I got it right.  Would appreciate input from @JBH and others.  I took off [tag:time] and [tag:creature-design] because they aren't part of the question (they might be important to the world, but that's not relevant here).  I added '[tag:light] but it says "visible spectrum."  But there isn't a tag for the non-visible spectrum, not one I could find.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Cyn [tag:electromagnetism] may be a better fit as that would include non-visible light such as infrared radiation. As you say, the [tag:light] tag specifically focuses on electromagnetic radiation that falls in the visible spectrum. The Electromagnetism tag though would include the entire spectrum.

Comment: @LiamMorris I made the change.  Though technically these shapes are visible...just not in regular light.

Comment: @Cyn and EVERYBODY ELSE!  What on earth are you all doing?  *Let the OP make the changes to their question!*  I don't see a single response in comments by the OP, which means not one of you has had permission to make the changes.  Unless you can prove you can read the OP's mind, stick to fixing grammar and misspelling.

Comment: Makeitso, you're being put through the wringer a bit.  People aren't helping you understand our site.  Our [help/on-topic] explains that "the goal of the site is to help you build your world, not to tell your story."  It seems you're looking for the perpetrator's *reasons,* which is storybuilding (off-topic), rather than *how they manifest,* which is worldbuilding (on-topic).  Worldbuilding concerns the rules and systems of your world.  Storybuilding is about circumstances, actions, and plot.  We can't read your aliens' minds.  And everybody else *please wait for the OP to respond.*

Comment: @JBH Huh?  All I did was tweak the tags so they matched the question.  I didn't even change grammar or spelling, let alone anything else in the text.

Comment: @Cyn did you have the OP's permission to make that change?  How do you know that it reflects the OP's intent?  The [Help Center page about editing](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/editing) states that edits should NOT change the OP's intent.  Changing tags w/o the OP's permission changes intent.  I apologize for behaving like a steam roller, but Makeitso is a new user and a lot of things are happening too quickly to this question without his involvement.  That should not be our default behavior. (To make a point, how do you or Liam know [tag:electromagnetism] is even appropriate?)

Comment: @JBH “How do you know it reflects the OP’s intent?” Because otherwise the changes would have been reverted. Look at the edit history, my change was completely, and quite rightly, overwritten as it did not match the OP’s intent. If the electromagnetism tag did not match the OP’s intent either, it would have been removed, simple as that. Also, i was stating that electromagnetism would be more appropriate than light as it includes both visible and non-visible light, which the OP referenced when they said “infra-red”, hinting at the tag being relevant to the question.

Comment: @LiamMorris, you can't look at what the OP did *after* what you did and claim, "see!  I was right to do it!"  It's bad behavior.  Please stop trying to justify it.  (Especially with a new user who doesn't understand our site and is simply trusting you.)

Comment: @JBH Not sure what you mean here, i said the complete opposite of that. I said the *OP* was right to revert my changes, not that *I* was right. As i stated, if a change did not match their intent, it would be reverted and was using my edit as an example. Cyn’s edit to the tag would have also been reverted if it did not match the OP’s intent. However, as it was not, it therefore must at least somewhat match the intent of the OP.

Comment: @LiamMorris, *Don't make non-grammatical changes without the OP's permission.* I can't be more clear than that.

Answer (score 2):

*Interdimensional "map" markers*

Those who can travel between dimensions of spacetime are leaving themselves indicators that help orient them to specific locations in worlds that diverge greatly from their origin world.

Using a system invisible to most human eyes helps the travelers remain unknowable while they travel, at least until a society is advanced enough to create technology that will detect the markers. Once the society can detect these patterns, it will be considered acceptable to interact with the humans of that world.

In the world in the picture, the differences are small enough that the markers remain within similar building sites rather than being out in an open area.